# Tabular Model and Analysis Service and ODBC

Tags: odbc, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, sql-server-2019, polybase

From SQL Server 2019, how do I connect to SQL Server Analysis Server (Tabular Model) / Azure Analysis Service using `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` command?

I would like to connect to it using Polybase and extract data from the Tabular data model.

I installed the latest drivers for the Tabular model:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions

Thanks,
grajee